# How to change the color of check and border in checkbox

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

**Want to do**

I want to make checkbox with [4 patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYXDO.png).
To achieve this, I want to know,

① How to change the color of check.

② How to change the color of frame border of checkbox.

I already tried this code and changed the background's color. However it doesn't work enough to achieve what I want.

```
//change the color of background in a checkbox
android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use property `android:button` to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

1.create a xml file `checkbox_background.xml` in folder `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_checked="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
      <item android:state_checked="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

2.set the `android:button` property of `CheckBox` to `checkbox_background`:

```
  <CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/check_box"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:button="@drawable/checkbox_background" />
```

Note： You can also set other status of checkbox in the `item`  of `selector` .

Comment: Thank you for an Answer. I already know that **android:button** will help and tried setting image to **@drawable/checked**. However, I can't change the color of check(✔) when checked.

Comment: Why not use two images to switch between the two statuses (`state_checked` and `state_checked`) ? You can use one image while the CheckBox is checked.

Comment: I knew I can switch. Problem was image which I set. I used the image from **https://fonts.google.com/icons** but I couldn't find checkbox which I can change the color of check. Changed using image and solved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually define various attributes in xml.
Here is an example - you need to modify it to your specific use case:

```
          <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:colorAccent="@color/checkboxcolor"
            android:buttonTint="@color/checkboxcolor" />
```

You can of course change the android:background to something else.
Also notice the android:button can be any drawable, but I am not using it and then set it to @null. So you should be able to achieve your desired result by working with these xml attributes such as the background (any drawable - here I  am just using a built in drawable from android, but you can use your own drawable. You can then have a border defined inside that custom drawable if you want.

Comment: I understand that **android:button** help to custom checkBox with image but I couldn't make black check and gray checkbox.(Second pattern)